# Generating subgroup of $\langle \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\},\cdot\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, rational-numbers

Does such a subgroup even exist?
My guess is That it is $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$
Any help?

Comment: The prime numbers will give you a smaller generating set.

Comment: Set-theoretic difference or relative complement is denoted by “**$\setminus$**” (via `\setminus`), **not** “$/$”, so
$$A \setminus B = \{x ∈ A;~ x \notin B\}.$$
Please edit your question accordingly and pass this important piece of information to anyone you catch making the same mistake. This is haunting mathematics way too much.

Comment: Edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper subgroup cannot generate the whole group. The set of nonzero integers is a generating *set* for the group $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},{\cdot})$, because every nonzero rational can be written as $ab^{-1}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

However, there is a more “economical” generating set, namely the set of (positive) primes together with $-1$, because every nonzero rational number is, possibly up to the sign, a product of (positive) primes or reciprocal thereof.

This is a *minimal* set of generators, because removing even one element yields a set that doesn't generate the group.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb Z\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$ is indeed a generating **set** for $\Bbb Q\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$. (This is not a subgroup.)

This is simply because any element of $\Bbb Q\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$ can be written as $pq^{-1}$ for some $p, q \in \Bbb Z\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$.
By definition of the subgroup generated by the set, any element of the above form is indeed present in the subgroup generated by $\Bbb Z\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$.

---

As Kenny Wong pointed out in the comments, you can actually make do with a smaller set.
Consider the set $P = \{p \in \Bbb N : p \text{ is a prime}\}.$
Then, the set $P \cup \{-1\}$ is a generating set of $\Bbb Q\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$ as well.

To see, we just note that any positive integer can be written as a product of elements of $P$. Including $-1$ lets us write any element of $\Bbb Z\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$ as an element of $P \cup \{-1\}$.

Since the former generates $\Bbb Q\color{red}{\setminus}\{0\}$, we are done.

---

Note that (as k.stm points out), the symbol '$/$' is typically used for quotient and not set-difference, which is what you probably wanted. The correct symbol for that is '$\setminus$'.
(This is why I've written it above in red.)

Comment: +1 for marking every single instance of set difference red.

Comment: @k.stm except the last one :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I was wondering if I should point that out myself ;-)